# How does CaCert work in the ActiveMerchant, Paypal Adaptive Gem?

Tags: rubygems, paypal, certificate

I'm confused about paypal accepting the CAcert that is provided in the ActiveMerchant and Paypal Adaptive Gems as a default fallback.  Does paypal trust the CAcert so it just automatically works with having to set anything on the Paypal site?

It may be because I have limited knowledge about how certs work.  But I was under the impression that the receiver needs to know the signature of the senders certificate.

Does paypal have the CAcerts on file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cacert.pem is about you trusting PayPal, not the other way around. Basically cacert.pem holds the master list of trusted root certificates, and underneath that Paypal have a certificate that you implicitly trust. Active Merchant bundle cacert.pem becuase it is often located in a different place on every server, and hard to locate.